# Need help converting PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have this php code:

```
$lines = file("data.csv");
$nested = array();
$links = array();

// first, create a structure that contains the connections between elements
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  list($child, $parent) = explode(",", $line);
  if (trim($child) == trim($parent)) {
    $nested[$parent] = null;
  } else {
    // add it to the children of parent
    $links[$parent][] = $child;
  }
}

function process(&$arr) {
  global $links;
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // no more children => stop recursion
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $links)) {
      $array[$key] = null;
      continue;
    }
    // insert its children
    $arr[$key] = array_flip($links[$key]);
    // recurse down
    process($arr[$key]);
  }
}


function print_html($multi_dimensional_array)
{
    $m = $multi_dimensional_array;
    $keys = array();

    foreach($m as $key=>$value) {
            $keys[] = $key;
    }

    $i = 0;

    while($i < count($multi_dimensional_array)) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$keys[$i].'</a>';
        if(is_array($multi_dimensional_array[$keys[$i]])) {
                echo '<ul>';
                print_html($multi_dimensional_array[$keys[$i]]);
                echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
        $i++;
    }
}

process($nested);

print_html($nested);
```

The data.csv format is (value,parent), an example would be:

```
one,one
two,two
three,three
sub_one,one
sub_one2,one
sub_two,two
sub_two2,two
sub_two3,two
sub_three,three
sub_sub_one,sub_one
sub_sub_one2,sub_one
```

Basically this what this PHP code does is create a multidimensional array that contains the parent name as key and the childs as values, and if a child also contains sub childs then it would be a key which contains subkeys, etc... and it will then print an html formatted list for that array.

How could I use C# to do what this php code does?

Comment: I think you need to try it yourself first and find out what problems you have. This site won't write all of your code for you. Start doing it, face the problem. If the problem is specific enough and well-phrased, you'll get help here

Comment: Agree with Dyppl -- The two languages are different and have different strengths.  You would be doing yourself a disservice if you didn't take the effort to try this task yourself.

Comment: To give you somewhere to start, I'd suggest looking at `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C# aren't like arrays in PHP. You'll probably need to implement the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to get the desired data structure. That's just a pointer to the right (I think) direction for a small part of your task. If you do end up using the pattern, consider `Dictionary<string, TComposite>` for the type of children collection.

Comment: Thanks, I end up using Dictionary<string, string>, it was easier than with php.